# Find the largest value of each row in Matlab and divide each number in that row by the number

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalize

I have a 133120x4 matrix in Matlab.

I would like to find the largest value in each row, and divide every element in that row by that particular value.

Do I need to use some sort of loop? For example: I find the amount of rows in that matrix (133120), and iterate the loop that amount of times, then I go row by row and use the max function to return the largest value in that row, and divide each element in that row by the returned value from max.

Or is there a quicker way of doing this?

Thanks

EDIT (for clarification):

lets call my 133120x4 matrix `A`. I want to divide every element in a row by the largest value in that row. Since max and element-division are vectorized, would the solution simply be:

`A_normal = A / max(A)`

resulting in a 133120x4 matrix, but within each row, the largest value would be 1.

Is this correct? EDIT: It is not correct, and am still trying to figure out solution. Help from the community is greatly appreciated

Comment: No, no loop required. Both `max` and element-wise division are vectorized.

Comment: please see the update, would this be the solution? Thanks

Comment: @2step is there something impeding you from trying it?

Comment: my solution results in a 133120x1 vector, not the desired 133120x4 matrix

Comment: @2step then, you should be quite ready to answer the question you added in the edit. Is that correct? No, its not.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for `max` and `rdivide`?

Comment: @beaker yes, it wasn't particularly helpful. Only way I can think of getting around the problem is to use a loop, but according to you guys the loop isn't necessary.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yep, please see the edit. I answered the question, that the solution is still not correct. Please see my comment on your post, because your solution is not correct either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the maximum with `max`, repeat the result N(=4) times so there is one per each element and then element wise division
!

```
newMat=mat./repmat(max(mat,[],2),[1 size(mat,2)]);]
```

or in R2016b or newer just

```
newMat=mat./max(mat,[],2);
```

Comment: Sorry I accidentally edited your comment instead of adding a new one - I am new to the forum forgive the lack of forum etiquette.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on your syntax? I have used your method with some dummy variables and it hasn't worked.

 `C = [0 2 45 5; 1 1 3 4; 3 3 44 0.3];`
`newC = C./ max(C, [], 4);`
It resulted in a 3x4 matrix with every element equal to 1, except for the first element which was NaN. It should have resulted in
`newC = [0 0.044 1 0.111; 0.25 0.25 0.75 1; 0.682 0.682 1 0.0068]`

Comment: @2step What does that `4` mean in `max(C, [], 4)`? You should probably try the solution someone gives you as is rather than modifying it on your own and claiming it doesn't work.

Comment: assumed it was the argument for dimensions. Previously got an error for mismatch of dimension sizes, so changed it to 4, but upon revision the solution actually works.

Comment: Why guess? The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) tells you exactly what that parameter is: "`M = max(A,[],dim)` returns the largest elements along dimension `dim`. For example, if `A` is a matrix, then `max(A,[],2)` is a column vector containing the maximum value of each row."